# Can't add canvas inside a div using three.js

Tags: three.js, svelte

Hello I'm trying to add canvas with a sense using three.js I have

```html
<div id="earth3D" bind:this={earth3DCanvas} />
```

and in order to add canvase in my js section, I do

```js
let earth3DCanvas;


    onMount(() => {
        const child = document.createElement(renderer.domElement);
        earth3DCanvas.appendChild(child);
    });
```

but for some reason I'm getting this error and I have no idea what it means.

```
VM2002:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('[object HTMLCanvasElement]') is not a valid name.
    at HTMLDocument.createElement (<anonymous>:1:1536)
    at http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:51519:30
    at run (http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:14:16)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:430:49
    at flush (http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:245:21)
    at init (http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:520:13)
    at new App (http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:51598:7)
    at http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:51609:17
    at http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:51618:3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a `container` first then `onMount` add the renderer to this container

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let container;
    onMount(async () => {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
        renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    });
</script>
<div id="container" bind:this={container} />
```

Here is a working repl

https://svelte.dev/repl/446c6476fc0444b19ec95c0044564b96?version=3.44.2

here is the fix if you want to use a conditional statement

```
<script>
    const initContainer = (node) => {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
        renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        node.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }
</script>
{#if condition}
    <div id="container" use:initContainer />
{/if}
```

here is a working repl using this approach

https://svelte.dev/repl/446c6476fc0444b19ec95c0044564b96?version=3.44.2

Comment: this is my new script
```js
 onMount(async () => {
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
   antialias: true,
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
  renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
  renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  earth3DCanvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 });
```
but the error is still there `App.svelte:80 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')`

Comment: @LAYTOR did you import onMount!

Comment: yp here is full code if you want it https://gist.github.com/laycookie/54a271f2855a69067e4221f667d6e284

Comment: @LAYTOR you are usning two instances of onMount, i updated my answer with a working repl

Comment: wait so what is causing the error is this because I have multiple onMount?

Comment: @LAYTOR i just read your code and what is causing the error is that you are binding `earth3DCanvas` inside of an if statement and you can't do that it will never be binded, you can solve this by using an action instead even though it will have a great performance impact to do so in your case

Comment: @LAYTOR see the updated answer

Comment: @LAYTOR great, congrats! please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Document.createElement()` expects a *tag name* as parameter (so a string like 'canvas' or 'div'), but you're passing it an HTMLCanvasElement object instead.

It's like you were attempting to recreate an already existing canvas.

I am not sure what your actual goal is, but if you want to create and append a brand new canvas, then you would do:

```js
onMount(() => {
    const child = document.createElement('canvas');
    earth3DCanvas.appendChild(child);
});
```

If you instead want to append the canvas referred to by `renderer.domElement` to your container div:

```js
onMount(() => {
    earth3DCanvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
});
```

Note that if the canvas was already part of the DOM (which seems to be the case given the `renderer.domElement` name?), then it will be moved, not duplicated.

Comment: you can create canvase with three.js by using `document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)` but this puts the canvase on body and I want to appendChild on a div with ID of earth3DCanvas I did try to use `earth3DCanvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);` at the begining but it gives me this error. `App.svelte:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')`